# Datepart function error in sql server

Tags: c#

```
select case  when datepart (mm,getdate())>3 then 'abc' else 2 end
```

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'abc' to data type
>   int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your values returned from `case` must be the same type.

```
select case  when datepart (mm,getdate())>3 then 'abc' else '2' end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
select CASE WHEN
       datepart (mm,getdate())>3 then 'abc' else '2'
       END
```

From [`CASE (Transact-SQL)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/ms181765.aspx)

> The data types of else_result_expression and any result_expression
>   must be the same or must be an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this

```
select case  when datepart (mm,getdate())>3 then 'abc' else '2' end
```